# How can I edit one of my created tags

Tags: support, tags

If I have created a tag that is not so clear, does not make sense or whatever (needs to be changed), how can I fix it?

I need to fix this tag:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/1m

Comment: Tag now removed. Though you should have been able to edit your own question to remove it, which is effectively deleting it.

Comment: The question was http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112321/basic-database-design-use-a-another-table-or-colum in case anyone's interested

Comment: I now we can remove it from question, but Do not know how to remove it from tags List. Just to make sure, it is not used by any one else, It id not leading somewhere. I thought, Mistakes caught and fixed early, cost less!

Comment: I think that if it's not used it won't get suggested - I've just tried  typing "1" into the tag field and "1m" wasn't suggested. Now there might be a delay for caching so it would be best to try again tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was contused as still can see it in tags list, but you are right, it is cashing problem. Hope its gone, when I next see SO

Comment: I've just checked again and typing "1" doesn't suggest "1m". So as long as you remove the tag the same day it appears it won't get into the "suggested tags" list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't delete, or edit tags. Put in a request for an admin to do so if you feel it is necessary. All-the-more reason to give careful thought to the tags you create and use.

Comment: Thanks mate, how do we make such a humble request to admin ?

Comment: Email `team@stackoverflow.com`